# FindObjectOfType Issues

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a pop up UI on death but I seem to have trouble using "FindObjectOfType" to trigger my DeathUI code from my game manager.

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float slowness = 10f;

    public void Start()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", 0);
    }

    public void EndGame()
    {
        StartCoroutine(DeathScreen());
    }

    IEnumerator DeathScreen()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1f / slowness;
        Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.fixedDeltaTime / slowness;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f / slowness);

        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.fixedDeltaTime * slowness;

        //SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
        Debug.Log("death");
        FindObjectOfType<DeathUI>().deathUI();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class DeathUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool GameOver = false;

    public GameObject deathMenuUI;

    public void deathUI ()
    {
        Debug.Log("game over");
        deathMenuUI.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        GameOver = true;
    }
}
```

I get the Debug in the Gamemanager but not in the DeathUI... Thank you!

Comment: Do you get any errors? E.g. a `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: No errors, I just can't get the deathUI working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FindObjectOfType will not find a disabled object. As stated in the Unity Docs [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html)

> Returns the first active loaded object of Type type.

You'll need to have your DeathUi GameObject enabled to use FindObjectOfType or reference it in your GameManager class:

```
[SerializeField]
private DeathUI deathUi;

// ...

Debug.Log("death");
deathUi.deathUI();
```

Comment: Ahh I see! Thank you. I moved my code to my game manager entirely so I don't have to use FindObjectOfType! :)